# Options for Sending Emails from Desktop / How does Access do it?

Tags: javascript, email, electron, nodemailer, quasar-framework

I have written a desktop application that is used for secretaries to put on some types of dog sports.  It's written in JavaScript using the Quasar Framework and ElectronJS to make it desktop only. It has to be desktop and not online because many of these sports are held in locations that don't have WiFi or any cell services.

Sending email confirmations is a critical part of the software.  Currently, I have it so that users can send emails either via SMTP or the default email Client.

The Client is a pain because 1) opens 70ish email windows that the users have to then manually click send individually so they will be sent out and, 2) it doesn't allow attachments (I just use mailto:)

SMTP is a pain because most email providers don't like SMTP logging in and sending that many emails all at once, and so blocks most of them.  It works, and I have it set up so the user can select like 10 people at a time to send the emails to, but it still takes more time.  This way does allow attachments (I use Node to send the emails).

My question: is there any other option?

There is rival software out there written in Microsoft Access that can generate the emails, with attachments, and automatically send them out through Outlook. The email providers seem fine with this type of bulk email sending.

However, I code on my Mac, so don't use Outlook, though I could possibly detect the OS type and if it's Windows use an alternative email building method.

I thought I'd ask the wide world and see if I do have any other options for sending emails.  I have spent hours and hours googling this and haven't found anything... so maybe my answer is just no.  :P